# Gnome 3 display problem

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graphical errors in Gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103488/graphical-errors-in-gnome-shell)

When I switch from ubuntu GUI to Gnome 3, all the graphics look messed up.
The task bar,the buttons....everything looks so gibberish and also the color scheme is messed up too.

Comment: Can you give some extra detail about your problem? Screenshot will be great!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)